# Neo4j REST API List All Labels returns labels when graph is empty?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, node-neo4j

I'm currently working on a REST API wrapper for Neo4j written in node.js.

Why does the REST API return labels of nodes that are removed?
Can I get all labels of existing nodes?

Code can be found at:
https://github.com/Stofkn/node-neo4j  (main.js method listAllLabels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are part of the database metainformation. They will not be cleaned when the node is removed.

Those labels are also attached to other kinds of meta-info, like indexes etc.

Comment: Is their a reason why this metadata is kept? The database doesn't use it for indexes nor labels on nodes. Is their an easy way to find out which labels are currently in use? (without traversing the whole graph)